# Reference showing no proper subgroups of p-adic orthogonal groups surject onto mod p orthogonal groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, galois-representations

I am looking for a reference for the following statement:

Let $O$ be an orthogonal group associated to a nondegenerate quadratic form of rank $r$ over the p-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$. Suppose $r$ is large (I think $r > 8$ should be enough). I believe it is true that any closed subgroup $S \subset O(\mathbb Z_p)$ which surjects onto $O(\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z)$ must be all of $O(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Does anyone know a reference for this fact? I am also interested in the analogous question where one replaces orthogonal groups with unitary groups.

In the case $r = 8$, as Eric Rains has pointed out to me, the finite Weyl group $W(E_8)$ is a proper subgroup of $O^+_8(\mathbb Z_2)$ which surjects onto $O^+_8(\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z)$, so the hypothesis $r > 8$ is needed. In particular I am aware of the paper by Vasiu "[Surjectivity Criteria for p-adic representations: Part I](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00229-003-0402-4)" but it appears to omit this rank 8 counterexample, and so the claimed classification in Theorem 1.3 appears to have some omissions. I would be happy to be corrected here if I am missing something. There are many excellent ideas in Vasiu's paper, and Eric Rains has sketched to me a method for patching Vasiu's arguments. Still, I am wondering if there might already be a reference available.

Comment: I don't have time to check this, but have you tried to understand the Frattini subgroup? On p393 of Lubotzky-Segal's book "Subgroup growth", they show that for all but finitely many $p$, the Frattini subgroup is the kernel of the reduction map, but I think that is for simply connected groups. Maybe similar ideas apply? (I took a quick look at Vasiu's paper and he didn't seem to mention Frattini subgroups)

Comment: Naïvely, one might expect that it's not just $r \le 8$, but specifically $r = 8$, that's the problem, since strange things can happen in the presence of triality. \\ A quick look at Vasiu's Theorem 1.3 suggests that your case might be related to the condition in Theorem 1.3(d) on $G_2$ subgroups.  Of course a rank-$4$ special orthogonal algebraic group over a field has no proper, non-trivial, connected, normal algebraic subgroups, but it *does* have a $G_2$ subgroup, and maybe an appropriate relaxation of the hypothesis on $H$ in Theorem 1.3(d) would capture what's going wrong.

Comment: For $p \ne 2$, your $S$ must contain, for each isotropic hyperplane in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^r$, an order-$2$ element lifting the corresponding reflection.  Perhaps one can combine this with an analogue of Cartan–Dieudonné (which holds over $\mathbb Z_p$ for $p \ne 2$)?

Comment: @Willchen I haven't looked at Frattini subgroups, but I also don't understand your idea. I'm mostly interested in a reference for the cases p = 2 and p = 3, since I think the cases p > 3 shouldn't be too difficult. Would your idea help with that, or is it only related to large p?

Comment: @LSpice Eric Rains also showed me counterexamples for r = 4, 5, 6, 7.  If you're asking about what is leading Vasiu to miss this case, Eric Rains also pointed out to me that one of the issues occurs on page 349, where he's discussing \PGL_4 and claiming to prove \PGL_4(\Z/4\Z)\to \PGL_4(\F_2) does not split. He reduces to
the problem of showing that no central extension of \SL_4(\F_2) lifts
mod 4, but the issue is that there a central extension of \SL_4(\F_2)
appearing as a proper subgroup of \SL_4(\Z/4\Z).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448120/reference-showing-no-proper-subgroups-of-p-adic-orthogonal-groups-surject-onto-m#comment1157956_448120), so much for [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448120/reference-showing-no-proper-subgroups-of-p-adic-orthogonal-groups-surject-onto-m#comment1157906_448120) guess!  Were the $r \le 8$ counterexamples all still for $p = 2$? I'd still think it might be productive to reason [thus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448120/reference-showing-no-proper-subgroups-of-p-adic-orthogonal-groups-surject-onto-m#comment1157908_448120) for $p \ne 2$.

Comment: @AaronLandesman I wasn't aware that you were only interested in the case for $p = 2,3$! For any $p$, your desired statement is equiv. to the Frattini subgroup of $G(Z_p)$ being the kernel of the reduction map. This kernel is pro-$p$, and since Frattini subgroups are easy to understand for pro-$p$ groups, one is led to study the Frattini subgroup of the finite group $G(\mathbb{Z}_p)/G_2$, where $G_i$ is the kernel of the reduction map to $\mathbb{Z}_p/p^i\mathbb{Z}_p$. This is what Lubotzky does for large $p$. For small $p$ you'd need to be more careful but I think a similar approach can work.

Comment: @LSpice There are also counterexamples for p = 3, namely O_3(F_3), which is related to the well-known counterexample for GL_2(F_3), and there's also a failure for O_4^+(F_3). Thanks again to Eric Rains for pointing this out to me. I think your argument shows you get some reflections in O_3(Z/9Z) as lifts of those in O_3(Z/3Z), but not that you get all of them.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448120/reference-showing-no-proper-subgroups-of-p-adic-orthogonal-groups-surject-onto-m#comment1158086_448120), I was only claiming that every reflection in the orthogonal group downstairs has a lift, not automatically that every reflection upstairs must lie in $S$.  I thought perhaps that there was some way to fill the gap left by the fact that not every reflection is obviously forced into $S$ that way, but counterexamples for $p = 3$ indicate that it doesn't work.

Comment: @LSpice Ok, thank you very much for thinking about it.

Comment: @WillChen Ok, thank you for suggesting this possible approach.